# Template error with Angular Bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I searched prior to posting question and cannot find something to help. Basically, am using Angular and Bootstrap with the ui.angular.js. For the likes of me, I cannot get the accordion to work because of reference to accordion.html and accordion-group.html based on the error I get from dev tools.

Using some quick help from the internet, I did the following:

html:

```
    <div ng-controller="pptController">
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.open = !status.open">Toggle last panel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.isFirstDisabled = ! status.isFirstDisabled">Enable / Disable first panel</button>
  </p>

  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
    Open only one at a time
  </label>
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
      <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

javascript in my controller:

```
app.controller('pptController', ['$scope', 'pptService', function ($scope, pptService) {

    $scope.ppt = [];

    pptService.getPpt().then(function (results) {

        $scope.ppt = results.data;

    }, function (error) {
        //alert(error.data.message);
    });

  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
    }
  ];

  $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
  };

  $scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isFirstDisabled: false
  };    

}]);
```

And the error I get in Chrome dev tools:

[image]

I know I am missing things here and it should be quite simple. Hoping someone can quickly help me out here in detail!

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Bootstrap uses a standalone template file.  Ensure you are including `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` along with the `ui-bootstrap.js` file.

You can see this is being caused by ui-bootstrap not having the template:

```
.directive('accordion', function () {
   return {
       restrict:'EA',
       controller:'AccordionController',
       transclude: true,
       replace: false,
       templateUrl: 'template/accordion/accordion.html'
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply seems that template file cannot be loaded. Make sure you can navigate to the file http://localhost:9000/...../accordion.html from within the browser...

Most likely typo in specifying template location...

Comment: But I am not setting a template anywhere and not sure why this would use any kind of template cache. That said, this location does not exist because it isn't being used.

Comment: That means you didn't include template files to your solution. Without template files, angular accordion directive will not work. Just download template folder with its content from github and place it respectively in your site and your code will work...